# What's the logic behind stop value of range function with negative step value in python

Tags: python, range, logic

My question is very simple.
I'm new to python and I recently learnt about `range()` in python. And I go through an sample program in that problem they asked to print reverse multiplication table of 3 using range function  And my code is

```
for i in range(30,3,-3):
           print(i)
```

But the output is not same as I expected. The output does not included 3. I don't know why.
My question the last value should be (stop value -1) i.e., 2 in this case. So 3 should also to be printed but not so. Please explain why.
Does I misunderstood the logic? If so please explain.

Comment: Would you expect 30 in `list(range(3,30))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python docs for [range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) says the following: :

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = >start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

This means the stop argument isn't included in the range calculation.

Comment: So constraints for a positive step value is i>=0 and r[i]<stop.  Isn't it?

Comment: @SarweshArivazhagan Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

`range()` excludes the stop point when generating your list (well actually they return a generator). You should change `3` to `2`, then it will include 3